# How to restrict voting button to 'To' address and not send to 'Cc' in outlook via powershell?

Tags: php, email, powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0

Powershell Script[script1.ps1] -:

```
param(
[string]$username,
[string]$username1,
)

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "$username1"
$Mail.Cc = "$username"
$Mail.Subject = "SUBJECT"
$Mail.Body = "--content--"


$mail.VotingOptions = "Approve;Reject"

$Mail.Send()
```

Php Code -:

```
<?php
  $connection = oci_connect("username","password","db_name");
  $lname = $_SESSION['lead_name'];
  $main_query=oci_parse($connection,"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD= '$lname'");
  oci_execute($main_query,OCI_DEFAULT);
  while($res = oci_fetch_array($main_query)) 
      {
        $mail= $res['USERNAME'];        
      } 
      $_SESSION['mail_id']=$mail;
      $cc = $_SESSION['mail'];

      $username = $cc;
      $username1 = $_SESSION['mail_id'];

    $psScriptPath = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Website_LMS\\Powershell\\script1.ps1";
    $query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -username '$username'< NUL -username1 '$username1'< NUL");
      oci_close($connection);
  ?>
```

Powershell Script is used to send email to outlook.
All these parameters username,username1 are sent from php script via shell exec command. These two are email address.

Now i want to use the voting button to approve or reject a leave which is triggered to the email addresses menetioned. I want the voting button is sent to username1 only i.e "To" addresses and not to "cc" addresses.
I want to implement this via powershell.

Comment: So far as I know you can't do this directly though Outlook itself. Why do you think a shell manipulating Outlook would have that ability?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - I am not sure whether it can. I tried customizing the email through a powershell script and it does allow me to do some modification but having to do something like the one I mentioned in the query here,I am not sure whether it is possible or not. Further, if its not possible through powershell then is there any other method to do that?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to send 2 mails, one with the voting options, and one without. But this may not suit your particular need/situation.

Answer (score 2):

Since the voting buttons (= the information on what to vote) are part of the mail, like the text and the subject, it is not possible to just make them visible to some of the recipients. Outlook (or better, the server, most likely Exchange) will send the very same email to all recipients, regardless whether they are addressed via `To`, `Cc` or `Bcc`.

That's by design, as stated in [RFC2822 (Internet Message Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.3):

> The destination fields specify the recipients of the message.  Each
> destination field may have one or more addresses, and each of the
> addresses indicate the intended recipients of the message.  **The only
> difference between the three fields is how each is used.**

You can simply send two Mails with the same content, except for the buttons:

```
param(
[string]$username,
[string]$username1,
)

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail1 = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail2 = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail1.To = "$username1"
$Mail2.To = "$username"
$Mail1.Subject = "SUBJECT"
$Mail1.Body = "--content--"
$Mail2.Subject = "SUBJECT"
$Mail2.Body = "--content--"


$mail1.VotingOptions = "Approve;Reject"

$Mail1.Send()
$Mail2.Send()
```

To clear things up for the recipients, you could add a text to the mails, stating that this mail is also sent to `$username`.